# ProgressBar not updating after changing back to the view

Tags: android

I've got a TabHost which displays two tabs. My first tab has a SeekBar on it which when changed, changes the value of an object `ObjectA.setValue(newValue)`.

My second tab is an ExpandableList. The list -- when I've got a group expanded -- will reflect the value of ObjectA in a ProgressBar:

```
public View getChildView(int groupIndex, int childIndex, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ... // ObjectA is retrieved

    LinearLayout layout;

    if (convertView == null) {
        layout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(MyApp.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rooms_room_list_row, parent, false);
    } else {
        layout = (LinearLayout) convertView; 
    }

    final ProgressBar pbLevel = (ProgressBar)layout.findViewById(R.id.ddLevel);       
    pbLevel.setProgress(objectA.getValue());
```

This works good, except in the following scenario:

1. I go to my 1st view and set a value of 50
2. I switch to my 2nd tab, and expand the group. The ProgressBar shows 50%, as expected.
3. I switch back to my 1st tab and change the value of 50 to a value of 5
4. When I switch back to my 2nd tab, since the group was already expanded Android automatically re-creates the view. A breakpoint in the `getChildView` method is hit where I can verify that my new objectA value is set to 5 (again, as expected) and I can watch the ProgressBar's value get set to 5, but the screen doesn't reflect this change -- it's still stuck on showing 50%. If I collapse the group and re-open it, it works and will now reflect the value of 5%.

So what's going on when I simply switch back to the view? Why won't my screen reflect 5% after running through the `getChildView` method the first time while the view is being re-created?

Comment: Is `getChildView()` getting called for *all* of the views? Sometimes the `ListView` will call `getView()` just to get the dimensions of items. Did you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: `getChildView()` is being called once per child when I switch back to the tab. I don't do anything with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() - if the view is already being re-created by Android, should I still need to call that somewhere?

Comment: It tells the adapter's `ListView` that the data (wherever ObjectA is coming from) has changed and the views need to be updated. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()).

Comment: So you are suggesting then that when I switch back to the tab, android  is only calling `getChildView()` to figure out a measurement, and that the view data I give it is discarded?

Comment: It might be, I dont think the content will be re-rendered unless you call `notifyDatasetChanged()`.